# Broken spring security adding an aspect

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, aop, spring-aop

I've just created an aspect to validate an input parameter in my login method. I have a service implementing UserDetailsService interface in spring security (Spring 4.2.1.RELEASE). My aspect is very simple for now, just calling jointPoint.proceed(), not validating input parameter yet:

```
@Aspect
public class LoginAspect {
    @Around(value="@annotation(LoginAnnotation)")
    public void loadByUserNameLoginValidation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

My service:

```
@LoginAnnotation
public class MyUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    //Retrieve User Details from database
    @LoginAnnotation
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        //Retrieve user details code
        //.....
        //.....
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

Debugging the code, I've found that loadedUser is null in Spring's DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser method:

```
    if (loadedUser == null) {
        throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(
                "UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
    }
```

The moment I remove my custom annotation @LoginAnnotation from my service, everything works perfectly. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that was it:

```
@Around(value="@annotation(LoginAnnotation)")
public Object loadByUserNameLoginValidation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

the result has to be returned from the aspect or it will be null.